# 2 scripts on the same page breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a custom jquery for my site aswell as an lightbox query. But it seems i cannot get both to work the the same time. Its always 1 of them working, depending on the order they come in. heres the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox({
                maxHeight: screen.height * 0.6,
                maxWidth: screen.width * 0.6
            });
        });
</script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /* Menu */
            $("#menu li:last").css("margin-right", "0");
            $("#menu ul.sub li:last").css("margin-right", "0");
            $("#menu li#menues a").hover(function() {
                $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeIn(200);
            });
            $("#menu").hover(function() { }, function() {
                $(".sub").fadeOut(200);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you including two copies of jQuery onto your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
$("#menu li#menues a").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeIn(200);
});
```

Uses the single parameter call for `hover()` http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2

This was added in jQuery 1.4, and you are using 1.3.2.

Either:

Update your jQuery.

---

Or use the two parameter function:

```
$("#menu li#menues a").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeIn(200);
}, null);
```

That way the anonymous function will be called only on mouseenter, change the order of the params if you want it called on mouseleave.

If you want it to fade in/out:

```
$("#menu li#menues a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeIn(200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeOut(200);
    });
```

---

If you need to use the same function for both, while using jQuery 1.3.2 use:

```
function menuLinkHover(){
    $(this).siblings(".sub").fadeIn(200);
}

$("#menu li#menues a").hover(menuLinkHover, menuLinkHover);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

You have included the jQuery twice ..

Remove this line of code

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
```

Comment: It's not an answer. You could leave just a comment. :)

Comment: My custom script still doesnt work properly. but if i delete the lightbox script it will. so somethings wrong.. the problem with my script is that when it has done fadein and shall execute fadeout it doesnt happen, maybe bcuz of the function-call?

Comment: @Saeed Neamati, the question is answered this way, so we call it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some scripts extend the jQuery object, it appears Lightbox is one of them.

By including a reference to the jQuery script twice, as the page loads:

- the jQuery object will be added to the DOM,
- then extended for lightbox,
- then a new jQuery object will be added to the DOM without the extensions

so the script that depends on lightbox will not run.

Removing the second jQuery `script` tag should fix this.

Comment: Why doesnt my script work then? it works when im not using the lightbox

Comment: What errors are being thrown? Are you able to view the console using FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: Cant even seem to get the event triggered(the fadeout), though this works without lightbox on the page.

Comment: Does the `$("#menu")` selector return the correct elements to register the anonymous functions to handle the events?

Comment: i put a breakpiont on the first row of the fadeoff function, but it doesnt get there

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the code that registers the event handler to make sure the function is getting wired as an event handler. I've also updated the answer to reference some code in your question.

Comment: @Jimmy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1153/discussion-between-stuperuser-and-jimmy)